# sys/socket.h and winsock.h No such file or directory on stm32cubeIDE and windows

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, stm32, freertos

**Solved :** The undefined variable are defined as FreeRTOS_AF_INET in the freertos_socket.h  I only looked for PF_INET as it was what was used in the exemple. I just had to replace them.

**Summary :**

- Specs
- Abstract
- What I want to do
- What I have done
- Where I am blocking
- Notes
- Question
- Files (cheatSheet and main.c)

**Specs**

- OS : Windows 10 pro
- Microcontroller / board : STM32H723ZG
- gcc : gcc (MinGW.org GCC Build-2) 9.2.0
- MCU toolchain : GNU tools for stm32 (10.3-2021.10) (downloaded stmCubeIde a couple months ago)
- MCU GCC compiler : gcc
- Language standard : GNU11

**Abstract**

I am using an stm32h7zg on windows 10 usgin STM32CubeIDE.
I created a simple project in STM32CubeMX. I then ported "FreeRTOS" and "FreeRTOS plus TCP". I was able to initialize the TCP part of the project (calling FreeRTOS_IPInit). I am now trying to open a socket using the function :

```
xListeningSocket = FreeRTOS_socket( PF_INET,
                                    SOCK_STREAM,  /* SOCK_STREAM for TCP. */
                                    IPPROTO_TCP );
```

When compiling, I get 3 errors :

- error: 'PF_INET' undeclared (first use in this function)
- error: 'SOCK_STREAM' undeclared (first use in this function)
- error: 'IPPROTO_TCP' undeclared (first use in this function)

I need to include either sys/socket.h for linux or winsock.h for windows.
But when I try to include any of those I get :

fatal error: winsock.h: No such file or directory

I tried to include :

- winsock.h
- Winsock.h
- winsock2.h
- Winsock2.h
- sys/socket.h
- socket.h

What should I include for stm32?

**What I want to do**

I want to use an STM32H723ZG as a client sending TCP message to a Raspberry Pi 3B+ set as a server in python.
So far I would like to be able to ping the STM32.

To do so, I have tried using lwIP embedded as a middlware from STM32CubeMX but I move to porting "FreeRTOS" and "FreeRTOS plus TCP" (an extension of FreeRTOS able to handle TCP communication" to a simple project generated in STM32CubeMX.
This was recommended because this way I control more what I use and I avoid using the HAL library that have a reputation for being buggy and I avoid using CMIS or whatever layer they added between their FreeRTOS and C.

**What I have done**

I was successful in porting FreeRTOS and create a couple tasks running at the same time.

I started adding the "FreeRTOS plus TCP" part following FreeRTOS's guide : https://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS-Plus/FreeRTOS_Plus_TCP/TCP_Networking_Tutorial.html

I then did the initializationa and startup that took me a bit of time with all the debugging, missing files, functions etc.

I made a cheatSheet to be able to track what I have done, I will add it at the end of the post as code because of formating.

**Where I am blocking**

I am now at the step of creating a TCP socket : https://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS-Plus/FreeRTOS_Plus_TCP/TCP_Networking_Tutorial_TCP_Client_and_Server.html

I basicaly copy pasted the exemple for a server and the exemple for receiving TCP data. I fixed undeclared functions, undeclared values etc.

I am now left with 3 errors :

- error: 'PF_INET' undeclared (first use in this function)
- error: 'SOCK_STREAM' undeclared (first use in this function)
- error: 'IPPROTO_TCP' undeclared (first use in this function)

Those errors are solved in windows by including winsocket and in linux by including sys/socket.h.

I tried to include :

- winsock.h
- Winsock.h
- winsock2.h
- Winsock2.h
- sys/socket.h
- socket.h

None of those worked, I always get `fatal error: winsock.h: No such file or directory`

I also tried this :

```
#ifdef __linux__  // include the socket library
    #include <sys/socket.h>
#elif _WIN32
    #include <Winsock2.h>
#endif
```

In that case, I go back to getting the 3 errors, meaning that it did not enter any of the ifs.

Maybe I could replace "IPPROTO_TCP" by 0 (read something like that online) but that still doesn't solve the 2 others.

I also tried changing "PF_INET" by "AF_INET" c.f. : https://community.st.com/s/question/0D53W00001vBZS1SAO/i-want-to-make-raspberry-pie-a-client-and-connect-it-to-the-server But it did not remove the error.

**Notes**

I made a simple C file including winsock2.h and compiled it in the terminal with gcc ("gcc client.c") and it compiled without error which was expected.

I recently move a bunch of files from my C drive to D drive but the project was created after I moved to the D drive (the tests with FreeRTOS [but not the plus TCP part] were also made after the drive relocation).

In the software Everything which allows you to find any file in your computer, I typed winsock2.h and I got that :

[Researche result in Everything for "winsock2.h"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjgAY.png)

**Question**

1. Which header should I include to create sockets in an STM32 project?
2. Could I define by myself the 3 undefined variables by creating them in a separate file? If so, can you guide me with some links on how it would work?
3. Do you see a problem with my project preventing me to create socket ?

Thank you in advance for taking the time to read this and to help me.

**Files**

Cheat sheet to create a project with STM32 and porting FreeRTOS:

```
###########################
#####    CubeMx :     #####
###########################

1) Set a timer in Sys.
2) Set the rest of what I need but make sure not to set freeRTOS in middlware (because we will port from official freeRTOS).

############################
#####    freeRTOS :    #####
############################

1) Add the freeRTOS files to the project:
 - config (and set it)
 - sources
 - includes
 - compiler port (GCC)
 - memory manager (heap4)

2) Add the folders freeRTOS the the project's path.

3) Include the folder freeRTOS to the project.

4) In the main.c :
Add the librairies:
 - "FreeRTOS.h"
 - "task.h"
For each task
 - create the task handle : TaskHandle_t xLedTaskHandle;
 - initialise the function : void vLedTask(void *pvParameters);
 - create the task in the main function : xTaskCreate(vLedTask, "Led task", 128, NULL, 1, &xLedTaskHandle);
 - define the function : void vLedTask(void *pvParameters){for (;;){HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_0);
                                                HAL_Delay(200);}}
Start the RTOS in the main function : vTaskStartScheduler();

5) Delete the double declaration of sys_tick, svc_handler and pendSV_handler in main.c.

##########################
#####    TCP/IP :    #####
##########################

info : https://forums.freertos.org/t/guide-to-setting-up-freertos-tcp-ip-in-stm32f767zi-nucleo/13503

1) Include to the file the folder freeRTOS plus TCP IP:
 - configIP
 - source
 - include
 - common
 - networkInterface stm32xxx
 - compiler
 - bufferManagement (bufferAllocation2.c)

2) Complete the compiler files pack_struct_end.h and pack_struct_start.h.
https://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS-Plus/FreeRTOS_Plus_TCP/Embedded_Compiler_Porting.html
Just put __attribute__( (packed) ); in the end but nothing in the start.

3) Complete the file freertosconfigip.h
https://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS-Plus/FreeRTOS_Plus_TCP/TCP_IP_Configuration.html
https://github.com/FreeRTOS/FreeRTOS-Plus-TCP/tree/a3f418a20dd05c5aecb362f52ee7344a606ac766/source/portable/NetworkInterface/STM32Hxx
set : 
#define ipconfigBYTE_ORDER                              pdFREERTOS_LITTLE_ENDIAN     /* because I use DHCP */
#define ipconfigNUM_NETWORK_BUFFER_DESCRIPTORS          64
#define ipconfigZERO_COPY_RX_DRIVER                     1
#define ipconfigZERO_COPY_TX_DRIVER                     1
#define ipconfigDRIVER_INCLUDED_TX_IP_CHECKSUM      1
#define ipconfigDRIVER_INCLUDED_RX_IP_CHECKSUM      1

4) Replace stm32h7xx_hal_eth.c and stm32h7xx_hal_eth.h with stm32hxx_hal_eth.c, tm32h7xx_hal_eth.h and stm32hxx_hal_eth.h

5) Add the folders FreeRtosTcpIp tot he path.

6) Include the folder freeRtosPlus.

7) Modification of hal_config.h
Add :
#define ETH_TX_DESC_CNT         14U /* number of Ethernet Tx DMA descriptors */
#define ETH_RX_DESC_CNT         8U  /* number of Ethernet Rx DMA descriptors */
//mandatory
#define HAL_ETH_MODULE_ENABLED
#define USE_HAL_ETH_REGISTER_CALLBACKS     0U /* ETH register callback disabled     */
//mac add
#define ETH_MAC_ADDR0    ((uint8_t)0x02)
#define ETH_MAC_ADDR1    ((uint8_t)0x00)
//buffer size
#define ETH_RX_BUF_SIZE         1524U
#define ETH_TX_BUF_SIZE         1524U

Remove double declaration.

8) STM32 are little endian (because ARM)
ipconfigBYTE_ORDER must be set to pdFREERTOS_LITTLE_ENDIAN in FreeRTOSIPConfig.h
#define ipconfigBYTE_ORDER pdFREERTOS_LITTLE_ENDIAN

9) Add in flash
Add at the beginning in memory section :
AXI_RAM (xrw)   : ORIGIN = 0x24000000, LENGTH = 128K    /* .ethernet_data declared here. H723zg axi start at 2400 0000 ends at 2401 ffff */c

Add defore discard :
    .ethernet_data :
    {
        PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__ethernet_data_start = .);
        KEEP (*(SORT(.ethernet_data.*)))
        KEEP (*(.ethernet_data*))
        PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__ethernet_data_end = .);
    } >AXI_RAM

10) Delete the double declaration of DMATxDscrTab and Rx
One declaration in main.c and one declaration in NetworkInterface.c.
Delete the one in main.c as well as the ETH_init function in the main().

########################
#####    Code :    #####
########################

1) Includes:
/* Standard includes. */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctype.h>

/* FreeRTOS includes. */
#include <FreeRTOS.h>
#include "task.h"
#include "timers.h"
#include "queue.h"
#include "semphr.h"

/* FreeRTOS+TCP includes. */
#include "FreeRTOS_IP.h"
#include "FreeRTOS_Sockets.h"
#include "FreeRTOS_TCP_server.h"
#include "FreeRTOS_DHCP.h"
#include "tcp_mem_stats.h"
#include "NetworkBufferManagement.h"
#include "NetworkInterface.h"
#include "FreeRTOS_IP_Private.h"
#if( ipconfigMULTI_INTERFACE != 0 )
    #include "FreeRTOS_Routing.h"
    #include "FreeRTOS_ND.h"
#endif


2) Variables :
Mac address : static uint8_t ucMACAddress[ 6 ] = { 0x00, 0x80, 0xE1, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
IP : static const uint8_t ucIPAddress[ 4 ];
Mask : static const uint8_t ucNetMask[ 4 ];
Gateway : static const uint8_t ucGatewayAddress[ 4 ];
DNS server : static const uint8_t ucDNSServerAddress[ 4 ] = { 192, 168, 73, 220 };

3) TCP init
FreeRTOS_IPInit(ucIPAddress,
                    ucNetMask,
                    ucGatewayAddress,
                    ucDNSServerAddress,
                    ucMACAddress );

4) Hook function :
void vApplicationIPNetworkEventHook( eIPCallbackEvent_t eNetworkEvent )
{
static BaseType_t xTasksAlreadyCreated = pdFALSE;

    /* Both eNetworkUp and eNetworkDown events can be processed here. */
    if( eNetworkEvent == eNetworkUp )
    {
        /* Create the tasks that use the TCP/IP stack if they have not already
        been created. */
        if( xTasksAlreadyCreated == pdFALSE )
        {
            /*
             * For convenience, tasks that use FreeRTOS-Plus-TCP can be created here
             * to ensure they are not created before the network is usable.
             */

            xTasksAlreadyCreated = pdTRUE;
        }
    }
}

5) Add xApplicationGetRandomNumber in the main.c
https://github.com/htibosch/freertos_plus_projects/blob/master/plus/stm32F7/Src/main.c

/* Random Number Generator variable. */
static RNG_HandleTypeDef hrng;

/* Random Number Generator function*/
BaseType_t xApplicationGetRandomNumber( uint32_t *pulValue )
{
HAL_StatusTypeDef xResult;
BaseType_t xReturn;
uint32_t ulValue;

    xResult = HAL_RNG_GenerateRandomNumber( &hrng, &ulValue );
    if( xResult == HAL_OK )
    {
        xReturn = pdPASS;
        *pulValue = ulValue;
    }
    else
    {
        xReturn = pdFAIL;
    }
    return xReturn;
}

6) Add file stm32h7xx_hal_rng.h and  stm32h7xx_hal_rng.c
https://github.com/htibosch/freertos_plus_projects/blob/03415d5278f80abd66a163f87ae2534d4abf1fd5/plus/stm32F7/ST_Library/include/stm32f7xx_hal_rng.h#L947
Change #include "stm32f7xx_hal.h" to #include "stm32h7xx_hal.h" in stm32f7xx_hal_rng.c

7) Modify stm32h7xx_hal_conf.h to define RNG
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50709778/stm32-gnu-arm-linker-undefined-reference-to-function-with-eclipse

8)In freeRTOS_IP.c create the function ulApplicationGetNextSequenceNumber and add it to the header aswell.
Page 852 https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/um1905-description-of-stm32f7-hal-and-lowlayer-drivers-stmicroelectronics.pdf
extern uint32_t ulApplicationGetNextSequenceNumber( uint32_t ulSourceAddress, uint16_t usSourcePort, uint32_t ulDestinationAddress, uint16_t usDestinationPort )
{
    static RNG_HandleTypeDef hrng;
    uint32_t ans;
    /* General init */
    HAL_RNG_Init(&hrng);
    HAL_RNG_GenerateRandomNumber (&hrng, &ans);
    return ans;
}

9) In stm32h7xx_hal_def.h, move the #include "stm32h7xx.h" after the type definition (after line 60)
//source 1 : https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X00009XkdxwSAB/compiler-errors-unknown-type-name-hallocktypedef-and-halstatustypedef-using-cubemx-and-atollic-truestudio-71
//source 2 : https://www.openstm32.org/forumthread1225
//source 3 : https://www.openstm32.org/forumthread8293

##############################
#####    TCP server :    #####
##############################

Add defines
Create TCP server function creating
Create function to handle the received data
create void prvProcessData(char *cRxedData) function
#include <sys/socket.h>
```

The main.c :

```
/* Standard includes. */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctype.h>

//#include <winsock.h>

/*
#ifdef __linux__  // include the socket library
    #include <sys/socket.h>
#elif _WIN32
    #include <Winsock2.h>
#else
    #include "socket.h"
#endif
*/

/* cubeMX/HAL includes */
#include "main.h"
#include "string.h"

/* FreeRTOS includes. */
#include "FreeRTOS.h"
#include "task.h"
#include "timers.h"
#include "queue.h"
#include "semphr.h"

/* FreeRTOS+TCP includes. */
#include "FreeRTOS_IP.h"
#include "FreeRTOS_Sockets.h"
#include "FreeRTOS_DHCP.h"
#include "NetworkBufferManagement.h"
#include "NetworkInterface.h"
#include "phyHandling.h"
#if( ipconfigMULTI_INTERFACE != 0 )
    #include "FreeRTOS_Routing.h"
    #include "FreeRTOS_ND.h"
#endif

ETH_TxPacketConfig TxConfig;

#define usUsedStackSize 128
#define BUFFER_SIZE 512

/* cube mx generated handler */
ETH_HandleTypeDef heth;
UART_HandleTypeDef huart3;

/* task handlers */


/* The MAC address array is not declared const as the MAC address will
normally be read from an EEPROM and not hard coded (in real deployed applications).*/
static uint8_t ucMACAddress[ 6 ] = { 0x00, 0x80, 0xE1, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };

/* Define the network addressing.  These parameters will be used if either
ipconfigUDE_DHCP is 0 or if ipconfigUSE_DHCP is 1 but DHCP auto configuration failed. */
static const uint8_t ucIPAddress[ 4 ];
static const uint8_t ucNetMask[ 4 ];
static const uint8_t ucGatewayAddress[ 4 ];

/* The following is the address of the DNS server. */
static const uint8_t ucDNSServerAddress[ 4 ] = { 192, 168, 73, 220 };

/* Random Number Generator variable. */
static RNG_HandleTypeDef hrng;

/* cube MX generated function definitions */
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_USART3_UART_Init(void);
static void MX_USB_OTG_HS_USB_Init(void);

/* TCP function definition */
void vApplicationIPNetworkEventHook( eIPCallbackEvent_t eNetworkEvent );
BaseType_t xApplicationGetRandomNumber( uint32_t *pulValue );
void vCreateTCPServerSocket(void);
void prvProcessData(char *cRxedData, BaseType_t lBytesReceived);

/* task function definitions (the ones that doens't do tcp thing */
static void prvEchoClientRxTask(void *pvParameters);

int main(void)
{
    /* cube mx generated */
    HAL_Init();
    SystemClock_Config();
    MX_GPIO_Init();
    MX_USART3_UART_Init();
    MX_USB_OTG_HS_USB_Init();

    /* TCP init */
    FreeRTOS_IPInit(ucIPAddress,
                    ucNetMask,
                    ucGatewayAddress,
                    ucDNSServerAddress,
                    ucMACAddress );

    vCreateTCPServerSocket();

    /* task creation */


    /* starting rtos scheduler */
    vTaskStartScheduler();

    for(;;);
}

void vCreateTCPServerSocket(void)
{
    struct freertos_sockaddr xClient, xBindAddress;
    Socket_t xListeningSocket, xConnectedSocket;
    socklen_t xSize = sizeof( xClient );
    static const TickType_t xReceiveTimeOut = portMAX_DELAY;
    const BaseType_t xBacklog = 20;

    /* Attempt to open the socket. */
    xListeningSocket = FreeRTOS_socket( PF_INET,
                                        SOCK_STREAM,  /* SOCK_STREAM for TCP. */
                                        IPPROTO_TCP );

    /* Check the socket was created. */
    configASSERT( xListeningSocket != FREERTOS_INVALID_SOCKET );

    /* If FREERTOS_SO_RCVBUF or FREERTOS_SO_SNDBUF are to be used with
    FreeRTOS_setsockopt() to change the buffer sizes from their default then do
    it here!.  (see the FreeRTOS_setsockopt() documentation. */

    /* If ipconfigUSE_TCP_WIN is set to 1 and FREERTOS_SO_WIN_PROPERTIES is to
    be used with FreeRTOS_setsockopt() to change the sliding window size from
    its default then do it here! (see the FreeRTOS_setsockopt()
    documentation. */

    /* Set a time out so accept() will just wait for a connection. */
    FreeRTOS_setsockopt( xListeningSocket,
                         0,
                         FREERTOS_SO_RCVTIMEO,
                         &xReceiveTimeOut,
                         sizeof( xReceiveTimeOut ) );

    /* Set the listening port to 10000. */
    xBindAddress.sin_port = ( uint16_t ) 10000;
    xBindAddress.sin_port = FreeRTOS_htons( xBindAddress.sin_port );

    /* Bind the socket to the port that the client RTOS task will send to. */
    FreeRTOS_bind( xListeningSocket, &xBindAddress, sizeof( xBindAddress ) );

    /* Set the socket into a listening state so it can accept connections.
    The maximum number of simultaneous connections is limited to 20. */
    FreeRTOS_listen( xListeningSocket, xBacklog );

    for( ;; )
    {
        /* Wait for incoming connections. */
        xConnectedSocket = FreeRTOS_accept( xListeningSocket, &xClient, &xSize );
        configASSERT( xConnectedSocket != FREERTOS_INVALID_SOCKET );

        /* Spawn a RTOS task to handle the connection. */
        xTaskCreate( prvEchoClientRxTask,
                     "EchoServer",
                     usUsedStackSize,
                     ( void * ) xConnectedSocket,
                     tskIDLE_PRIORITY,
                     NULL );
    }
}

static void prvEchoClientRxTask( void *pvParameters )
{
    Socket_t xSocket;
    static char cRxedData[ BUFFER_SIZE ];
    BaseType_t lBytesReceived;

    /* It is assumed the socket has already been created and connected before
    being passed into this RTOS task using the RTOS task's parameter. */
    xSocket = ( Socket_t ) pvParameters;

    for( ;; )
    {
        /* Receive another block of data into the cRxedData buffer. */
        lBytesReceived = FreeRTOS_recv( xSocket, &cRxedData, BUFFER_SIZE, 0 );

        if( lBytesReceived > 0 )
        {
            /* Data was received, process it here. */
            prvProcessData(cRxedData, lBytesReceived);
        }
        else if( lBytesReceived == 0 )
        {
            /* No data was received, but FreeRTOS_recv() did not return an error.
            Timeout? */
        }
        else
        {
            /* Error (maybe the connected socket already shut down the socket?).
            Attempt graceful shutdown. */
            FreeRTOS_shutdown( xSocket, FREERTOS_SHUT_RDWR );
            break;
        }
    }

    /* The RTOS task will get here if an error is received on a read.  Ensure the
    socket has shut down (indicated by FreeRTOS_recv() returning a -pdFREERTOS_ERRNO_EINVAL
    error before closing the socket). */

    while( FreeRTOS_recv( xSocket, &cRxedData, BUFFER_SIZE, 0 ) >= 0 )
    {
        /* Wait for shutdown to complete.  If a receive block time is used then
        this delay will not be necessary as FreeRTOS_recv() will place the RTOS task
        into the Blocked state anyway. */
        vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS(250));

        /* Note - real applications should implement a timeout here, not just
        loop forever. */
    }

    /* Shutdown is complete and the socket can be safely closed. */
    FreeRTOS_closesocket( xSocket );

    /* Must not drop off the end of the RTOS task - delete the RTOS task. */
    vTaskDelete( NULL );
}

void prvProcessData(char *cRxedData, BaseType_t lBytesReceived)
{

}

void vApplicationIPNetworkEventHook( eIPCallbackEvent_t eNetworkEvent )
{
static BaseType_t xTasksAlreadyCreated = pdFALSE;

    /* Both eNetworkUp and eNetworkDown events can be processed here. */
    if( eNetworkEvent == eNetworkUp )
    {
        /* Create the tasks that use the TCP/IP stack if they have not already
        been created. */
        if( xTasksAlreadyCreated == pdFALSE )
        {
            /*
             * For convenience, tasks that use FreeRTOS-Plus-TCP can be created here
             * to ensure they are not created before the network is usable.
             */

            xTasksAlreadyCreated = pdTRUE;
        }
    }
}

BaseType_t xApplicationGetRandomNumber( uint32_t *pulValue )
{
HAL_StatusTypeDef xResult;
BaseType_t xReturn;
uint32_t ulValue;

    xResult = HAL_RNG_GenerateRandomNumber( &hrng, &ulValue );
    if( xResult == HAL_OK )
    {
        xReturn = pdPASS;
        *pulValue = ulValue;
    }
    else
    {
        xReturn = pdFAIL;
    }
    return xReturn;
}

void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  HAL_PWREx_ConfigSupply(PWR_LDO_SUPPLY);

  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE0);

  while(!__HAL_PWR_GET_FLAG(PWR_FLAG_VOSRDY)) {}

  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI48|RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_BYPASS;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSI48State = RCC_HSI48_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 4;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 275;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = 1;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = 4;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLR = 2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLRGE = RCC_PLL1VCIRANGE_1;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLVCOSEL = RCC_PLL1VCOWIDE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLFRACN = 0;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_D3PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_D1PCLK1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB3CLKDivider = RCC_APB3_DIV2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_APB1_DIV2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_APB2_DIV2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB4CLKDivider = RCC_APB4_DIV2;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_3) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

static void MX_USART3_UART_Init(void)
{
  huart3.Instance = USART3;
  huart3.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
  huart3.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart3.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart3.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart3.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart3.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart3.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  huart3.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONE_BIT_SAMPLE_DISABLE;
  huart3.Init.ClockPrescaler = UART_PRESCALER_DIV1;
  huart3.AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit = UART_ADVFEATURE_NO_INIT;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart3) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_UARTEx_SetTxFifoThreshold(&huart3, UART_TXFIFO_THRESHOLD_1_8) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_UARTEx_SetRxFifoThreshold(&huart3, UART_RXFIFO_THRESHOLD_1_8) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_UARTEx_DisableFifoMode(&huart3) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

static void MX_USB_OTG_HS_USB_Init(void)
{
}
//removed some of the cubeMX generated function because of stackoverflow's character number limitation.
```

Comment: Using Windows or Linux definitions on Freertos is pointless. Only use the FreeRTOS_Sockets.h definitions such as FREERTOS_AF_INET

Comment: "*I am using an stm32h7zg on windows 10 usgin STM32CubeIDE*" -- I take you to mean that you are *developing for* an stm32h7zg, using STM32CubeIDE running on Windows.   You seem to be saying that that the target OS is FreeRTOS.  When you are using cross tools like this, you must to rely on the features and libraries (only) of the target environment.  I guess your IDE is making this too transparent to you, such that you are confused about the difference between developing for the host (Windows) environment and for the target (FreeRTOS) environments.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Stark : I did include FreeRTOS_Socket.h and searched for PF_INET (since it is what they use in the exemple) in it but got no result so I stopped looking. There is however AF_INET so I think I have my answer there. John : I did understand that it was not compiling for windows nor for linux when i used the #ifdef. I thought that I had to include something else because the already included FreeRTOS_Socket.h hearder did not have the exemple's variable defined.